# What is the definition of $G$-equivariant sheaf?

Tags: representation-theory

I am confused about the first page of Bernstein-Lunts (there is a preview here https://books.google.com/books?id=mot8CwAAQBAJ&pg=PP3&dq=bernstein+lunts&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjT_IbM4ffSAhUBQiYKHZQXDlkQuwUIKTAC#v=onepage&q=bernstein%20lunts&f=false). If $G$ is a group, then a topological space $X$ is called a $G$-space if the multiplication map $m:G \times X \rightarrow X$ is continuous. They define maps $d_0,d_1,d_2,$ and $s_0$, and then say that a $G$-equivariant sheaf on $X$ is a pair $(F,\theta)$, where $F$ is a sheaf on $X$ and $\theta$ is an isomorphism $\theta:d_1^*F \cong d_0^*F$ satisfying a certain condition. What are the sheaves $d_0^*,d_1^*,$ and $d_2^*$?

The definition is discussed briefly in the following note, but Bernstein refers to Bernstein-Lunts for a precise definition. I'm trying to understand how, if $G$ is a $l$-group, a $G$-equivariant sheaf on a point is nothing but a smooth representation of $G$.

http://www.math.tau.ac.il/~bernstei/Publication_list/publication_texts/Bern_Stacks_2014.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you understand what the pullback sheaves are, and what the cocycle condition means in terms of them? That exposition seems quite confusing, since it uses the names like $d_0$ to refer to two different maps, one out of $G \times G \times X$, and the other out of $G \times X$.

A more clear explanation of what an equivariant sheaf is can be found in Chriss and Ginzburg's "Representation Theory and Complex Geometry". A preview of the chapter on equivariant K-theory can be found [here](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=OZlCAAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA231&ots=-lpHD5DbRj&dq=representation%20theory%20and%20complex%20geometry%20equivariant%20k-theory&pg=PA231#v=onepage&q=representation%20theory%20and%20complex%20geometry%20equivariant%20k-theory&f=false), all the information you're after is in the first few pages.